# how to do this in java

Tags: java

i have an integer with value  each time it will be assigned by routine i need to set it to another variable

```
int a=2;
if(a<=10)
{
b=10;
}
else if(a<=2)
{
b=2;
}
else
{
b=0;
}
```

it fails how can i do that ...because a satisifes both condition///

Comment: Can you explain what your trying to do?

Comment: yeah, your question makes little sense. Please rephrase.

Comment: `else if(c<=2)` where is `c` in your code?

Comment: b will always be 10 because your assign a to 2 right before the if/else conditions.

Comment: @Roflcoptr, no, it will always be 10.

Comment: a yes. I didn't see the else if

Comment: ....[wild goose chase](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wild-goose_chase).

Comment: This is such a good example in showing, why I prefer having the curly brackets on the same line as the method body/conditional statement/loop head. Completely unreadable code even though the code is very simple...

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
if (a <= 2) {
    a = 2
} else if (a <= 10) {
    a = 10;
} else {
    a = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
b = (a <= 10) ? ((a <= 2) ? 2 : 10) : 0;
```

???

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of you conditional checks, check the lower value first:

```
int a=2;   // test input, I guess

if (a<=2) {  
   b=2;                // for all a <= 2
} else if (a<=10) {  
   b=10;               // for 2 < a <= 10
} else {
   b=0;                // for a > 10
}
```

(that's what you wanted?)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
if (a <= 2) {
    b = 2;
} else if (a <= 10) {
    b = 10;
} else {
    b = 0;
}
```

This way the all conditions can be met.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a=2;  
if(a>2 && a<=10) { 
   b=10; 
} else if(a<=2) { 
   b=2; 
} else { 
   b=0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b=0;
if(a<=10) {
    b=10;
}
if(a<=2) {
    b=2;
}
```

Why the elses at all?

Comment: I would move the second if inside the 1st if, since if a is bigger than 10 than it cannot be less or equal than 2.

Comment: Sure. the main point is to get the code to actually run, because JIT will make it run well in practice.